# If I am traveling from India to US, am I allowed to carry spices on plane?

Tags: air-travel, usa, india

I would like to know the details regarding carrying spices while traveling by air from India to the US.

Answer (score 5):

In general, raw plant products are unacceptable, sufficiently processed plant products are acceptable--anything done to it that would destroy pests makes it acceptable.  Most spices fall into this category.  Unfortunately, the exact details are subject to change.

The complete list (which I'm having no luck finding now, I've seen it before) runs into the hundreds of pages.

You are required to declare **all** food (defined broadly, consider anything you eat or drink to be food) at entry, so long as you declare it if they find it unacceptable they just take it, no penalty.  Thus, while you don't want to bring anything obviously wrong (say, meat or fresh fruit), if you're not certain about it and it's not too expensive, bring it.

Comment: is it the [USDA APHIS](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/aphis/ourfocus/importexport) link that you're looking for?

Comment: @Dorothy No, the file I found had **far** more information.